# How to use if condition in Javascript RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to add some rules to *Imagus Firefox Extension*. I want to capture image parameter from Google Image Search and if it contains the string `th_` remove it and redirect. Otherwise just redirect.

**This is my RegEx**:

```
/^(?:(?:images|encrypted)\.)?google\.[^/]+/(?:imgres\?(?:[^&]+&)*?imgurl=)(.*)(?:th_)(.*)&imgrefurl=.*/gm
```

It works fine for URL's which contain string `th_` but for other links it breaks.

Here's the link to my work https://regexr.com/3omf5 Have a look and help. 
PS: Please note there are two links in the example.

Comment: Remove `(?:th_)` in your regex?

Comment: Try with optional quantifier(?). It checks for 0 or 1 occurrence. `(?:th_)?`

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't remove the 'th_' in result URL.

Comment: Can you please provide a simplified example with input and result?

Comment: @zᴉɹɥƆ  I've attached a simplified example to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer after a fight. And the regex works fine in the Extension.

**Ans:**

```
^(?:(?:images|encrypted)\.)?google\.[^/]+/(?:imgres\?(?:[^&]+&)*?imgurl=)(.*)(%2Fimages(?:[\d]{1,9})?%2F)(th_)?(.*)&imgrefurl=.*
```

**Here is th link with answer:**
https://regexr.com/3omfh

Comment: Well, fine, I was still looking :). You can accept your own answer als well. You still need to escape a slash here: ...`google\.[^/]+`-->\<--`/`...

Answer (score 0):

Add a `*` after `(?:th_)`, like:

```
^(?:(?:images|encrypted)\.)?google\.[^/]+/(?:imgres\?(?:[^&]+&)*?imgurl=)(.*)(?:th_)*(.*)&imgrefurl=.*
```

Comment: Then it doesn't remove the th_ from the first link.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(?:(?:images|encrypted)\.)?google\.[^/]+/(?:imgres\?(?:[^&]+&)*?imgurl=)(.*)(?:th_)(.*)&imgrefurl=.*)|(.+)
```

Matches your urls with th_ and replaces it or takes the whole url with the additional `|(.+)` (+ `^(?: ... )` around your regex). You need to replace it with `$1$2$3` then

Comment: Then it breaks the link2 which doesn't contain 'th_' then I tried using (?) after (?:th_)? then it doesn't remove the 'th_' from the link 1